# Does Moshiach bear our sins, in any sense?

Tags: sources-mekorot, messiah, reward-punishment, music, suffering

I know 'bear' is vague, but I have always been upset by the popular Jewish singer, Mordechai ben David's song, 'Yerusholayim Our Home'.

It contains the line, '***Suffering for years, from all our sins he bears.***'

Source: http://lyrics.wikia.com/wiki/Mordechai_Ben_David:Yerushalayim_Our_Home although http://classic.frumteens.com/topic.php?whichpage=20&pagesize=15&forum_title=&topic_title=lyrics&forum_id=30&topic_id=1434 has 'for all our sins he fears' but that is definitely wrong, based on the song https://open.spotify.com/track/2nswVbshfl9JkSDcz7UJxd

My question is, does this have any source?

Comment: sorta similar http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/61955/759

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! We can always use another Fred :) Thanks for sharing the question. Consider checking out this short [Beginners' Guide](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3887/8775) to Mi Yodeya. Hopefully we will  see you around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The source may be Sanhedrin 98a.

> ר' יהושע בן לוי אשכח לאליהו דהוי קיימי אפיתחא דמערתא דרבי שמעון בן יוחאי אמר ליה אתינא לעלמא דאתי אמר ליה אם ירצה אדון הזה אמר רבי יהושע בן לוי שנים ראיתי וקול ג' שמעתי אמר ליה אימת אתי משיח אמר ליה זיל שייליה לדידיה והיכא יתיב אפיתחא דקרתא ומאי סימניה יתיב ביני עניי סובלי חלאים וכולן שרו ואסירי בחד זימנא איהו שרי חד ואסיר חד אמר דילמא מבעינא דלא איעכב אזל לגביה אמר ליה שלום עליך רבי ומורי אמר ליה שלום עליך בר ליואי א"ל לאימת אתי מר א"ל היום אתא לגבי אליהו א"ל מאי אמר לך א"ל שלום עליך בר ליואי א"ל אבטחך לך ולאבוך לעלמא דאתי א"ל שקורי קא שקר בי דאמר לי היום אתינא ולא אתא א"ל הכי אמר לך (תהלים צה, ז) היום אם בקולו תשמעו
>
> Rabbi Yehoshua ben Levi met Eliyahu standing at the entrance of the cave of Rabi Shimon bar Yochai.
>   He *(R' YbL)* said to him, "Will I have a portion in the World to Come?"
>   He *(Eliyahu)* said to him, "If this Master *(the Shechina -Rashi)* wants".
>   Rabbi Yehoshua ben Levi said, "I saw two and the voice of a third *(the Shechinah -Rashi)* I heard."
>
> He *(R' YbL)* said to him, "When will the messiah come?"
>   He *(Eliyahu)* said to him, "Go ask him."
>   *(R' YbL)*"And where does he sit?"
>   *(Eliyahu)* "And the gates of the city."
>   *(R' YbL)* "And what is his sign?"
>   *(Eliyahu)* "He sits between the poor, **those suffering of sickness**. And all of them remove [their bandages] and tie them on at one time. And he removes one and ties one on [because] maybe he will be needed, so that he shouldn't be delayed."
>
> He *(R' YbL)* went to him *(the messiah)*. He *(R' YbL)* said to him, "Peace to you my rabbi and my master."
>   He *(the messiah)* said to him, "Peace to you son of Levi".
>   *(R' YbL)* "He said to him, "When is the master coming?"
>   He *(the messiah)* said to him, "Today."
>
> He *(R' YbL)* came to Eliyahu. He *(Eliyahu)* said to him, "What did he tell you?"
>   He *(R' YbL)* said to him, "Peace to you son of Levi."
>   He *(Eliyahu)* said to him, "I ensure for you and your father [a place] in the World to Come."
>   He *(R' YbL)* said to him, "He lied to me, that he said to me, 'today I will come'."
>   He *(Eliyahu)* said to him, "This is what he said to you, "Today if you listen to My Voice (Psa. 95:7)

Rashi there says:

> **those suffering of sickness**: They are wounded. And he is also wounded as its written, "And he was pained from our sins (Isa. 53:4)" and "Our sickness he carries (ibid.)"

Unfortunately I don't own one of the nice Ein Yaakov's. In there is a bit more of an explanation of what it means that Moshiach (or any tzaddik) suffers for the nation.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/73754/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33568/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/73835/759

Answer (score 4):

This is mentioned explicitly in the [Sefer Hassidim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sefer_Hasidim) (ed. Margolis: 528):

> משיח סובל עונות ישראל וגם הצדיקים גמורים סובלים יסורים עבור ישראל
>
> The messiah bears the sins of Isreal and also completely righteous people suffer afflictions on behalf of Israel.

Answer (score 2):

Another source that is pretty explicit is from [Midrash Pesikta Rabbati, chapter 36](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39324&hilite=673f8c19-5ad1-4c99-a31f-b0c46863b25a&st=%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%97&pgnum=351) which discusses Moshiach accepting upon himself responsibility for the sins of everyone who will be included in the final redemption.

> התחיל הקדוש ברוך הוא מתגר, עמו ו( ואומר. הללו שגגוזים הם אצלך עונותיהם עתידים להכגיםך בעול ברזל ועושים אותך )כעול( ]כעגל[ הזה שכהו עיניו ז(. ומשנקים את רוחך בעול י0. ובעונותיהם של אילו עתיד לשונך לידבק בחיכך. רצונך בכך. אטד
>   משיח לפני הקדוש ברוד הוא שמא אותו צער שנים רבות הם. אמר לו הקב׳׳ה חייך .וחיי ראשי שבוע. )אי!( ]אחת[ שגזרתי עליך. אם נפשך עציכה אני טורדן מעכשיו ט(. אמר לסגיו רכון העולמים בגילת גפשי ובשמחת לבי אני מקבל עלי על מגת שלא יאבד אחד מישראל. ולא חיים בלבד)יושיע( ]יושעו[ כימי ]אלא אף אותם שננוזים כעפר.
>   ולא מתים בלבד יושעו בימי אלא אף אותם מתים שמתו מימות אדם הראשון עד עכשיו[, ולא אילו בלבד אלא אף נפלים ]יושעו בימי[ ולא אילו בלבד יושעו כימי אלא )למי( ]כל מי[ שעלתה על דעתך להבראות ולא נבראו )בהם(. בכך אני
>   רוצה. בכך אני מקבל עלי י(.

Comment: Consider bolding and or translating the relevant text, and removing extraneous characters.